# How to add time delay to process more than 15 second in Actionscript?

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, time, while-loop, actionscript

So I have the following script to get all combination of an array :
'''

```
var value = new Array(40)
for (var i=0;i<value.length;i++){
    value[i]=i;
}
var comb_list = getAllComb(value,24);
trace(comb_list)
function getAllComb(values:Array, r:int):Array{
    var n = values.length;
    var result = new Array();
    var a = new Array(r);

    // initialize first combination
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    i = r - 1; // Index to keep track of maximum unsaturated element in array
    // a[0] can only be n-r+1 exactly once - our termination condition!
    var count = 0;
    while (a[0] < n - r + 1) {
        // If outer elements are saturated, keep decrementing i till you find unsaturated element
        while (i > 0 && a[i] == n - r + i) {
            i--;
        }
        result.push(a.slice())// pseudo-code to print array as space separated numbers
        count++;
        a[i]++;
        // Reset each outer element to prev element + 1
        while (i < r - 1) {
            a[i + 1] = a[i] + 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

'''

Running above script will get me:

Error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

How to add time delay each 14 seconds passed so that I can run the script? So, after 14 seconds passed, the program will wait for 50ms then continue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Normally, Flash Player is not a multi-threading environment. It operates as following: code execution > graphics rendering > code execution > graphics rendering > and so on. If you run an infinite loop, the next frame never comes, which is not normal.

Answer (score 3):

So, there's a simple (well, pretty much so) and working example of how to separate the heavy calculations part from the main thread so the main thread (which also handles UI and external events like user input) would run smoothly, while being able to read the progress and the results of the heavy calculations going under the hood. It also is in a form of a single class, this could be a bit confusing (until you understand how it works) but still easy to handle and modify.

Although the background AVM goes along the same execution flow (code execution > graphics rendering > code execution > graphics rendering > and so on), there are no graphics to render hence there's no need to anyhow limit the code execution time. As a result **Worker** thread is not a subject to 15 seconds limit, which, somehow, solves the problem.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import flash.concurrent.Mutex;

    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;

    public class MultiThreading extends Sprite
    {
        // These variables are needed by both the main and
        // subservient threads and will actually point to
        // the very same object instances, though from
        // the different sides of this application.
        private var B:ByteArray;
        private var W:Worker;
        private var M:Mutex;

        // Constructor method.
        public function MultiThreading() 
        {
            super();

            // This property is 'true' for the main thread
            // and 'false' for any Worker instance created.
            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial)
            {
                prepareProgress();
                prepareThread();
                startMain();
            }
            else
            {
                startWorker();
            }
        }

        // *** THE MAIN THREAD *** //

        private var P:Sprite;
        private var F:Sprite;

        // Prepares the progress bar graphics.
        private function prepareProgress():void
        {
            F = new Sprite;
            P = new Sprite;

            P.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
            P.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 10);
            P.graphics.endFill();
            P.scaleX = 0;

            F.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000);
            F.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 10);

            F.x = 10;
            F.y = 10;
            P.x = 10;
            P.y = 10;

            addChild(P);
            addChild(F);
        }

        // Prepares the subservient thread and shares
        // the ByteArray (the way to pass messages)
        // and the Mutex (the way to access the shared
        // resources in a multi-thread environment
        // without stepping on each others' toes).
        private function prepareThread():void
        {
            M = new Mutex;
            B = new ByteArray;
            B.shareable = true;
            B.writeObject(incomingMessage);

            W = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(loaderInfo.bytes);
            W.setSharedProperty("message", B);
            W.setSharedProperty("lock", M);
        }

        // Starts listening to what the background thread has to say
        // and also starts the background thread itself.
        private function startMain():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

            W.start();
        }

        private var incomingMessage:Object = {ready:0, total:100};

        private function onFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            // This method runs only 20-25 times a second.
            // We need to set a lock on the Mutex in order
            // to read the shared data without any risks
            // of colliding with the thread writing the
            // same data at the same moment of time.
            M.lock();

            B.position = 0;
            incomingMessage = B.readObject();

            M.unlock();

            // Display the current data.
            P.scaleX = incomingMessage.ready / incomingMessage.total;
            P.alpha = 1 - 0.5 * P.scaleX;

            // Kill the thread if it signalled it is done calculating.
            if (incomingMessage.terminate)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

                W.terminate();

                B.clear();

                B = null;
                M = null;
                W = null;
            }
        }

        // *** THE BACKGROUND WORKER PART *** //

        // I will use the same W, M and B variables to refer
        // the same Worker, Mutex and ByteArray respectively,
        // but you must keep in mind that this part of the code
        // runs on a different virtual machine, so it is the
        // different class instance thus its fields are not
        // the same quite as well.

        // Initialization.
        private function startWorker():void
        {
            W = Worker.current;
            M = W.getSharedProperty("lock");
            B = W.getSharedProperty("message");

            // Before starting the heavy calculations loop
            // we need to release the main thread which is
            // presently on W.start() instruction. I tried
            // without it and it gives a huuuge lag before
            // actually proceeding to intended work.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onWorking);
        }

        private function onWorking(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onWorking);

            var aMax:int = 10000000;

            // Very very long loop which might run
            // over the course of several seconds.
            for (var i:int = 0; i < aMax; i++)
            {
                // This subservient thread does not actually need to
                // write its status every single loop, so lets don't
                // explicitly lock the shared resources for they
                // might be in use by the main thread.
                if (M.tryLock())
                {
                    B.position = 0;
                    B.writeObject({ready:i, total:aMax});

                    M.unlock();
                }
            }

            // Let's notify the main thread that
            // the calculations are finally done.
            M.lock();

            B.position = 0;
            B.writeObject({ready:i, total:aMax, terminate:true});

            M.unlock();

            // Release the used variables and prepare to be terminated.
            M = null;
            B = null;
            W = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to your script needing a time delay, the problem is your while loops are making your script unresponsive for more than 15 seconds, triggering the script timeout error. Action Script only allows 15 seconds for your script to execute.

Your first while loop looks problematic, and I'm unclear how the value of a[0] changes to end the loop. Add a break to the loop or make sure the condition changes to allow the loop to end, and you should solve your problem. You can also considering adding continue statements to your embedded while loops if they are only supposed to run one time after they find an unsaturated value.

Personally, since you are using ActionScript, I'd suggest using objects and listeners for value changes instead of iterating over arrays checking for changes.

You could also add a manual timeout for your while loop, but would need to include logic for it to pick up where it left off.

```
//Set timer to 14 seconds
timeout = getTimer() + 14000;
while(true && timeout > getTimer()){
    trace("No Error");
}
```

Comment: The thing is if I change 40 and 24 to smaller number - to 10 and 5, for example. The program runs successfully and I get correct result (so, I conclude the loop will stop eventually). I'd guess the fact that C(40,24) is very big number is causing the program to be unresponsive. That's why I am curious is there a way to add "wait" inside the function.

Comment: It sounds like the operation is heavy. I've found in general that iterating over arrays in actionscript is slow. If it only needs to run the while loop through 10 values then it can do it under 15 seconds, and no error, it sounds like with 40/24 values to check, it takes longer than 15 seconds. You need to re-write you code in a way that limits how many values it checks in a cycle. Again, using objects and listeners will be the easy way to solve this, but if you really want to use while loops, you could potentially use the getTimer() function to break the loop if too much time has passed

Comment: Agree with @dprogramzis , you have to limit the amount of cycles the loop goes through, save the cycle integer and resume the next frame. Due to how heavy the processes are, there might also be a chance that the timer does not work as accurately. The best way is to limit cycles per frame.

Comment: @user1234567 No. If these calculations are **THAT** heavy, the best way is to resort to multi-threading. First, it is the right way to design AS3 applications with such a heavy calculations without ending up with stuttering UI, second it is the cool thing to do, and last but not least, in FP30 the cost of **getTimer** is increased literally thousandfold and calling it every loop iteration will be a huge performance problem by itself: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2499947

Comment: @Organis I'm not sure what you mean, AS3 isn't multithreaded nor does it support it.  It really depends on how often this function needs to run. You could use Worker class to spawn virtual instances and fake multiprocessing to process the data, but then you have to start dealing with things like concurrency. I still thing using a Class with listeners is a more elegant solution than manually iterating over the array. as events are less CPU intensive than polling.

Answer (score 1):

If you were used Adobe Animate (Flash), you could change the "Script Time Limit" from Publish setting page.
[image]